# How to write makefile.am's in subdirectories?

Tags: makefile, autotools

I am learning autotools. My top level directory structure is like this

```
Sample--
        src
        test
        inc
```

here *src* contains source files and *inc* contains include files and *test* contains files for test suites. Suppose i want to write a test suite which requires some libraries in *src* how to write Makefile.am's using ***SUBDIRS*** option in automake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never been sold on the idea of a separate directory for headers. That aside, the `src` `Makefile.am` can simply use the `AM_CPPFLAGS` variable:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/inc # and other preprocessor flags.
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = file_1.c file_2.c ... ../inc/file_1.h ../inc/file_2.h ...
```

Ideally, you would also include the headers in `libfoo_la_SOURCES` as above, since any changes in a header requires the recompilation of source files. By placing the headers in the `src` directory, we can simply list `file_1.h`, `file_2.h`, etc., in the `SOURCES` primary.

Since `-I$(srcdir)` is already provided [automatically](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Program-Variables), you don't need to add this option to `AM_CPPFLAGS`, provided the headers are included in the form `<file_1.h>` or `"file_1.h"`.

Furthermore, the headers will be installed by adding the following to `src/Makfile.am`:

```
libfoo_includedir = $(includedir)
libfoo_include_HEADERS = file_1.h file_2.h ...
```

A minimal top-level `Makefile.am` might look like:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install # AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) in configure.ac
SUBDIRS = src tests # depth-first ordering of build.
```

This leaves us with `test/Makefile.am` :

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src # or $(srcdir)/../src
check_PROGRAMS = foo_test
foo_test_SOURCES = foo_test.c
foo_test_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libfoo.la
```

Note the use of `top_builddir` - we want to be able to build 'out-of-tree'.

Finally, you might want to consider building libraries with headers of the form: `<foo/file_1.h>`. I think this is a better approach, as the leading directory provides a sort-of 'name space' for the library headers. e.g.,

```
libfoo_includedir = $(includedir)/foo # in foo/Makefile.am

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) # in test/Makefile.am
```

Comment: I tried it in the same way but giving this error "No rule to make target `all'.  Stop." at the directory i am trying to create a static library.

Comment: suppose i want to add a library to another library(suppose libfoo library requires another source files in other directory). How should i do it?. Is this correct way of doing?                   libfoo_la_LIBADD = $(top_srcdir)/src/another.la

Comment: foo_test_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/foo.la i this way  we add static libraries to our program. But how they are automatically created or we have create them manually, is there any way of doing it automatically when required